# adding button in cloudReco in vuforia sample

Tags: ios, vuforia

I need to add button instead of image on scanning through the camera. After scanning I am  able to display the image that I am getting from my web service.But I am not able to add the button nor its action is working on the TargetOverlay class.Can anybody let me know how to add a button/action in targetOverlay class?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are developing an iOS app.
It isn't possible to dynamically load a button as you loaded an image using webservices.
A **button** needs to be **compiled before you run** the application.

If you want ***you can dynamically change the background image of button*** as you did with the image before.

**To Overlay a button and implement its callbacks do the following:**

*Drag and drop* a button to your **TargetOverlayView.xib** file.

**In TargetOverlayView.h** add:

```
@property(retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *yourButton;

-(IBAction)onYourButtonClick(id)sender;
```

(link the both of them to your button in xib.)

**In TargetOverlayView.m implement callback:**

```
-(IBAction)onYourButtonClick:(id)sender
{
// Your code here
}
```

Comment: Any solution for Unity users?